# Structure group relating global cross sections of frame bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles

If I'm considering a parallelizable Riemannian manifold $M$ we have that the frame bundle has some structure group $G$. Is the group relating all possible global trivializations of the frame bundle still $G$? I would expect it to be maybe more restricted than the structure group linking arbitrary local trivializations on $M$.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. The frame bundle of any smooth $n$-manifold is $GL(n,\mathbf{R})$. For a Riemannian manifold this reduces to $O(n)$, but could reduce further depending on the holonomy of the metric. If the manifold is parallelizable then the frame bundle is trivial and any two trivializations differ by some $GL(n, \mathbf{R})$-valued function. But the question sounds as if you're assuming some reduction at the outset, or perhaps conflating reduction of the structure group and triviality of the frame bundle...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Your second sentence needs an edit.

Comment: Thanks Ted; you mean "The _structure group of the_ frame bundle ... is $GL(n, \mathbf{R})$"? <> (Nice to see you!)